# Version 3 Beta Login Logo Not Resizing

Tags: assets, control-panel, settings

The login page logo does not resize on Craft V3 Beta, but the site icon does, using the identical image. The images are resized to 500 x 500 when uploaded to the cp settings page, but the logo width is cropped to 300 X 412 approximately

I think this is a bug - is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Craft 3 bugs should go to https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues.  There is already one created for what you describe: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1428